# how pony set column comment

Tags: python, ponyorm

I want set Column comment with pony ,but I can't find the `comment` parameter,

I want comment column like below

```py
class User(db.Entity):
    __tablename__ = 'account_collection'
    uid = Required(str, max_len=50, comment='unique user id')
    name = Required(str, max_len=50, comment='username')
```

but it will not work and raise `TypeError: Attribute User.uid has unknown option 'comment'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pony doesn't support any kind of comments yet.
Maybe we'll add this feature someday.